# Show that operator is bounded and converges pointwisely but not in the operator norm

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, operator-theory

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $T_n:c_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined through $T_n(x_k)_k=x_n$.

First, I need to show that $T_n$ is bounded, which is the case if and only if $T_n$ is continuous. As every $x_k$ in $c_0$ converges to 0, then $T_n(x_k) \rightarrow T_n(0)$ since $x_n\rightarrow x_n$. Is that true?

Next I need to show that $T_n$ converges pointwisely to 0 which means for a sequence of operators that $T_nx\rightarrow Tx$. Why is that true?

The last thing I need to show is that the operator norm $||T_n||$ does not converge to 0. $||T_n||=\sup \frac{||T_nx||}{||x||}$ for $||x|| \neq 0$. Is it because $||T_nx||$ = ||x|| and hence it is the supremum of 1 which is not 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, I need to show that $T_n$ is bounded, which is the case if and only if $T_n$ is continuous. As every $x_k$ in $c_0$ converges to 0, then $T_n(x_k) \rightarrow T_n(0)$ since $x_n\rightarrow x_n$. Is that true?

You need to bound $|T_n(x)|$ by some multiple of $\|x\|$. If you simplify the former, and look at the definition of the latter, the answer should fall out.

What you have done is more relevant to showing pointwise convergence. Since $T_n(x) = x_n \to 0 = 0(x)$ as $n \to \infty$, for any $x \in c_0$, this means $T_n \to 0$ pointwise.

> The last thing I need to show is that the operator norm $||T_n||$ does not converge to 0. $||T_n||=\sup \frac{||T_nx||}{||x||}$ for $||x|| \neq 0$. Is it because $||T_nx||$ = ||x|| and hence it is the supremum of 1 which is not 0?

You should be careful with notation like $\|T_n x\|$. Remember, $T_n x$ is a real number, so absolute values $| \cdot |$ would be more precise than a generic norm $\| \cdot \|$ (which could be confused with the $c_0$ norm).

It is not true in general that $|T_n x| = \|x\|$. For example, if $x = (1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$, then $|T_n x| = 0 \neq 1 = \|x\|$ for any $n > 1$.

To prove this, you should come up with some sequence $(x^n_m)_m$, for any $n \in \Bbb{N}$, so that $T_n(x^n) = \|x^n\|$. The superscripts are not powers, but intended to show that the real sequence $x^n$ depends on $n$. Hint: the $x$ mentioned in the previous paragraph satisfies $T_1x = \|x\|$.